# Oracle - Index seems not to work. Still slow

Tags: database, performance, indexing

Oracle Database: 
I have a table with 400000 rows.
I create an index for field1.
**The following query is still very slow** (700ms):

```
select field1, field2
from table
where 
field1 = '0903400110106156' or
field1 = '0903400110106160' or
field1 = '0903400110106190' or
field1 = '0903400110106471' or
field1 = '0903400110106480' or
field1 = '0903400110106494' or
field1 = '0903500110100001' or
field1 = '0903500110100012' or
field1 = '0903500110100021' or
field1 = '0903500110100031' or
field1 = '0903500110100039' or
field1 = '0903500110100047' or
field1 = '0903500110100050'
```

I drop the index and I still get 700ms.
I create the index again and I still get 700ms.
What is wrong???

The create index statement:

```
CREATE INDEX myindex
ON table (field1)
```

EDIT: Explain Plan

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            |  Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                |     4 |    60 |     2 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL   | table          |     4 |    60 |     2 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("table"."field1"='0901690339400674')

Note: cpu costing is off
```

EDIT2: OK, I did a table analysis for 2 tables. table1 has the speed problem. table2 is a lot faster (10msec instead of 700msec) although its size is similar to table1. Strange speed problem!!! Please help...

```
chk     Owner   Name    Partition   Subpartition    Tablespace  NumRows  Blocks  EmptyBlocks    AvgSpace    ChainCnt    AvgRowLen   AvgSpaceFLBlocks    NumFLBlocks UserStats   GlobalStats LastAnalyzed     SampleSize Monitoring  Status                            PartType      PartInfo     IsExternal
TRUE    user    table1                             tablespace  484627   6858    182            878         777         103                                         NO          NO          15/3/2011 18:34  125977     NO          Normal, Successful Completion                                FALSE
TRUE    user    table2                             tablespace  366159   6480    176            786         16565       130                                         NO          NO          15/3/2011 18:34  89657      NO          Normal, Successful Completion                                FALSE
```

Comment: What does the execution plan for the query look like. Does it mention your index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Solved.

Yesterday before I leave work to go home I did a last try and my query was still slow (no index use).

Today in the morning before I do anything else I did another try and **suddenly the index works** and I get only 10 msec.

If you have any explanation please post it.

I am adding the last explain plan:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   |  Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                      |     1 |    23 |     4 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| table                |     1 |    23 |     4 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | myIndex              |     1 |       |     3 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("table"."field1"='0901690339400674')

Note: cpu costing is off
```

Comment: Changes to tables or indexes require that the Oracle database be stopped and restarted to take effect?

Comment: I did restart the database, and the server also. But it didn't help. Leaving it half a day on did help, but why? Is there a chance that Oracle needs time to create the indexes? And if so, how much time? Half a day? (I don't think so)

Answer (score 4):

The question is a bit old meanwhile but since I had the same problem right now and no answer worked for me here is the correct answer which is missing in my opinion. After creating an index use following statement to tell Oracle that there is a new index and it has to use it whenever possible.

```
ANALYZE TABLE <tablename> COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

As an alternative you can tell Oracle to compute statistics just in the moment you create a new index by:

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON table (field1) COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
where
field1 in ('0903500110100050', '0903500110100050', .. )
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether or not you have an index on field1.  The database has to read the entire table before it can satisfy an OR condition (or an IN predicate) on the WHERE clause.

It would be faster to put an index on field1 and request field2 for one field1 at a time (WHERE field1 = :value) in a loop.

Comment: I don't think that 13 queries will be faster than 1 query. But it's hard to tell without the execution plan.

Comment: OK, I tried only one condition in the where clause, namely where field1 = '0903400110106156'. I get 460ms!!! Something is going terribly wrong

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:  It depends on other factors, but 13 hits against an index file is usually faster than table scanning a 400,000 row table.

Comment: @Stefanos Kargas: Is field1 indexed?  Is field1 exactly 16 characters long?

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc: Not sure about that. As the query involves a non-indexed column as well there will be at least 3 IO operations per row (2 for the index lookup + 1 for the table row) plus the overhead of the hard parse on the server side. It is worth a test though (e.g. by using 13 SELECTs and a UNION ALL instead of a loop). Oh: and it obviously depends on the number of rows returned. If `field1` is not a primary key, each value might return more than one row (which might be another reason why a table scan is chosen)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:  Sounds good to me.  Try your SELECT - UNION on one of your 400,000 row tables.  :-)

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc: I don't think it will be slower than a loop :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:  I agree.  However, the original comparison was a SELECT with the OR predicate (or IN predicate).

Comment: 13 SELECTs with UNION ALL takes 5 secs

Comment: field1 is indexed and yes, it is exactly 16 chars

Comment: @Stefanos Kargas:  Then I don't understand why your explain plan shows a table access full (table scan).

Comment: Is there a chance oracle choses not to use the index for this table? I am certain the index exist.

Comment: @Stefanos Kargas: Usually, a database skips the index when the value in the WHERE clause doesn't match the format of the column.  That's why I asked you if field1 was defined as CHAR(16).  Another reason for skipping an index would be if the table scan was faster.  I'm not sure what's happening with your query and your Oracle table.

Answer (score 1):

Try an index on (field1, field2)

```
CREATE INDEX myindex
ON table (field1, field2)
```